# ASP.NET C# Umbraco 7 - Form Send Email & Save to DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, umbraco

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@using System.Net.Mail
@{
    Layout = "Master.cshtml";
}
@{
    var fullname="";
    var mobileno="";
    var email="";

    if (IsPost){
        fullname=!Request["fullname"].IsEmpty()?Request["fullname"]:"";
        mobileno=!Request["mobileno"].IsEmpty()?Request["mobileno"]:"";
        email=!Request["email"].IsEmpty()?Request["email"]:"";

        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("email@email.com", "Client");
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("receiver@email.com", "Admin"); 
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from,to);
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Host = "my1.hosting.com";
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email@email.com", "passwordemail");
        client.Port = 2525;

        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        mail.Subject = "Submitted Form by "+fullname;

        mail.Body += "<strong>Full Name</strong> : "+fullname;
        mail.Body += "<br /><strong>Mobile No</strong> : "+mobileno;
        mail.Body += "<br /><strong>Email Address</strong> : "+email;

        client.Send(mail);
    }
}
<form method="POST">
    <label>Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullname" >

    <label>Mobile No.</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobileno" >

    <label>Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" >

    <input type="submit" id="af-assist-submitBtn" value="Submit Now!"/>
</form>
```

the code above is only send to email....

and it's working...

but i would like to send email and also save to database...

Is there any plugin for umbraco for the form to make it simple?

and i want to view the form submitted in the list in somewhere in admin panel.

Answer (score 2):

There is a paid solution called Umbraco Forms that will do what you ask?